# Give a function uniformly continuous with respect to one metric and not with respect to another, while both induce the same topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would very much appreciate an example to the above question or some hints to construct one.

Such a function should not exist in normed vector spaces: If the topologies induced by two norms are equal the norms are äquivalent and vice versa.

Comment: Just a guess without having done the calculations: If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then so is $\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$, and both induce the same topology. But the former may be unbounded, while the latter is always bounded by 1, so that might make a difference when choosing the $\varepsilon$-balls for (uniform) continuity.

Comment: Try  the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ and the metric $D(x,y)=|x^{3}-y^{3}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $X=(0,1)$ (the open interval), $f(x)=1/x$, and two metrics on $X$, $d_1(x,y)=\lvert\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\rvert$, and $d_2(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$.

$f(x)$ is uniformly continuous under $d_1$; for $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon$, then for any $x,y$ such that $d_1(x,y)<\delta$ $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert = \lvert 1/x-1/y \rvert < \delta =\epsilon$.

Clearly $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $d_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!